# Treating belongsTo() that returns null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a model (request) that returns customer object base on it's id, it's receiving the id from a different machine so I want to treat non-existent values (i.e. id that doesn't exist returning the eloquent as null).

so for:

```php
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'site_user');
}
```

I've tried the following:

```php
public function getSiteUserAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('customer')) {
        $this->load('customer');
    }

    return $this->getRelation('customer') ?: $this->nullCustomer();
}
```

and `nullCustomer()` :

```php
private function nullCustomer()
{
    $nonExist = 'non-exist-customer';

    $siteUser = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection;
    $siteUser->first_name = $nonExist;
    $siteUser->last_name = $nonExist;
    $siteUser->email = $nonExist;

    return $siteUser;
}
```

Yet Laravel is returning an error I can't really make sense of:

```
Undefined property: App\Request::$site_user (View: /../../index.blade.php)`
```

it's obviously related to `getSiteUserAttribute()` which extrapolates `site_user`, but I can't understand what's the issue.

I can `isset()` for every place that this relation is called, but i'm working with a smart framework, so I doubt that would be the best practice.

Just to reiterate, I'm trying ot treat null `belongsTo()` that wouldn't break the view.

Comment: Isn't it just that you should use `siteUser` not `site_user` to use what you have defined in `getSiteUserAttribute` method?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite `nullCustomer()` to return `App\Customer` not `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`:
I have not tested it though.

```
private function nullCustomer()
{
    $nonExist = 'non-exist-customer';

    $siteUser = new \App\Customer;
    $siteUser->first_name = $nonExist;
    $siteUser->last_name = $nonExist;
    $siteUser->email = $nonExist;

    return $siteUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems site_user field and site_user attribute is mixed.

The easiest way to get rid of the confusion, rename the field as site_user_id

Answer (score 1):

As Murat Tutumlu said, you can't have a `site_user` attribute and a `getSiteUserAttribute()` accessor at the same time.

You can specify default values with [`withDefault()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method):

```php
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'site_user')
        ->withDefault([
            'first_name' => 'non-exist-customer',
            'last_name' => 'non-exist-customer',
            'email' => 'non-exist-customer'
        ]);
}
```